# Webgl and Android Color

Tags: android, colors, webgl

I draw some objects in webgl.
I need precise colors.

My object has color (200, 0, 255, 255) in Windows.
If I draw it in Android, my object has color (204, 0, 255, 255).

Can you tell why?

Comment: Will you really notice a variation of **4** in the Alpha channel value?

Comment: I need precise color because I want to pick a object at the color.

Comment: Well, the **color** is actually `(0, 255, 255)`. You can simply not take the Alpha value in account.